# how can i grid the button to the side of the bottom

Tags: python, tkinter, button, grid-layout

so what I wanna do is move the button from the middle to the side as shown in the image
i tried to grid it using button.grid(row=0, column=1) but it didnt work and the button didnt move
[image: The image am talking about]

so how do I do it?
here is my script:

```
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Notepad')
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/Hero/Documents/Visual Studio code/My project/notes.ico')
root.geometry("500x500")

root.tk.call("source", "C:/Users/Hero/Documents/Visual Studio code/My project/azure.tcl")
root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

def change_theme():
    if root.tk.call("ttk::style", "theme", "use") == "azure-dark":
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "light")
    else:
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('azure-dark')
style.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar", background="grey", bordercolor="black", arrowcolor="white")

barframe = Frame()
barframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

text=Text(root, font=("Georgia, 24"), yscrollcommand=scroll.set, bg='#292929')
scroll.config(command=text.yview)
text.pack()

fonts = ttk.Button(barframe, text='Size and Font', width=15, style='Accent.TButton')
calculater = ttk.Button(root, text='Calculater', width=15, style='Accent.TButton')
fonts.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the frame at the bottom left using `anchor`:

```
barframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w')
```